# Can't run Minecraft... a GLX Problem?

Tags: minecraft

^ That.

```
Error Report:
Time: 5/26/13 8:06 PM
Description: Failed to start game


org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:684)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:854)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:784)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:765)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:235)
    at avv.a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:507)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

---

```
-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.5.0-31-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_21, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 23182920 bytes (22 MB) / 58785792 bytes (56 MB) up to 872415232 bytes (832 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    LWJGL: 2.4.2
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

Please help?

Answer (score 2):

### Minecraft

#### [Install Sun Java](https://askubuntu.com/a/56119/13247)

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the 32bit or 64bit Linux "compressed binary file" - it has a ".tar.gz" file extension and uncompress it

```
tar -xvf jre-7-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

JRE 7 package is extracted into ./jre1.7.0 directory. Now move the JRE 7 directory to `/usr/lib`

```
sudo mv ./jre1.7.0* /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0
```

Afterwards run the following to get a list of currently installed java alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will get output as:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path Priority Status
————————————————————
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode
1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 manual mode
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java 63 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Remember the last number and press enter to exit this utility i.e. in this example remember the number `2`.

If only one alternative is shown then remember the number `0`

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java 3
```

This will add your new JRE 7 installation into alternatives list i.e. use the remembered number + 1 i.e. 3 in the example above. Now configure java to use the Oracle Java JRE

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will see output similar one below - choose the number of jre1.7.0 i.e. `3`:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path Priority Status
————————————————————
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode
1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 manual mode
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java 63 manual mode
3 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java 3 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode.
```

N.B. if there was no previous java installation then the new JRE will be the default and you will not see the above.

Check the version of you new JRE 7 installation:

```
java -version
```

Should produce

```
java version “1.7.0”
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

#### [Update LWJGL](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL) (if you still have issues)

1. Download [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/download.php)
2. Extract files
3. Place **.so** files in **~/.minecraft/bin/natives/**